# Suggestion to rename Tag [office365] to [microsoft-office-365]

Tags: discussion

Since the current notation for MS Office tags is `microsoft-office-VERSION` e.g. `microsoft-office-2019`, I would suggest to apply that notation to MS Office 365 as well.

Currently the tag is named `office365` (tag link: [office365](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/office365)) which does not seem consistent with any other tag notation. Unless I overlooked s.th. ...

Comment: They're different; while Microsoft Office is a standalone application (you pay-it-once), Office 365 is a subscription service. Office 365 doesn't include Microsoft in the original name so I think the tag is fine as it is. (probably renaming it won't be a problem either)

Comment: @CaldeiraG interesting, where did you get the information that eg. Office 2019 **does** have Microsoft in it's name and Office 365 **doesn't**? I can find any differences on Microsoft's website?!

Comment: *does not seem consistent with any other tag notation*... Office apps are in quite another category than Office 365. Office 365 is an entire ecosystem of products and services, which happens to *include* the traditional desktop applications.

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica can you elaborate? Not sure I agree. Essentially it's the same type of difference you have between the windows versions. Win 10, same as Office365 is a continues update scheme. Desktop application (offline installation files) and Apps (windows online store installations), is a different aspect which applies to a broad range of application. It's not a MS Office specific issue.

Comment: This is Microsoft's [list of the services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-service-descriptions-technet-library) that are part of the Office 365 platform. It's extensive.

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica yes, but this is not the feature list for "Office 365 desktop applications/apps". What you are referring to are the cloud services available by MS (within the Office domain) like one drive etc. This is not what my question here is about, I'm only referring to the (installable) standalone client application (as desktop application and online store app). Although there are also called "Office 365" (and have a certain "connection" with the standalone applications) cloud services are something fundamentally different.

Comment: While *you* may only have the desktop app in mind when discussing the `[office365]` tag, the tag itself is for the entire subscription-based Office 365 platform, and thus it's inaccurate to think of it as equivalent to the Office desktop apps.

Comment: @IsayReinstateMonica ah, ok now I understand what you mean, thanks. Let me give that a few thoughts. Maybe the Office365 desktop&store apps would be better described by a new tag...

Comment: "which does not seem consistent with any other tag notation": well, https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10 does not carry the vendor, either.

Comment: @bers not sure I get the point... can you elaborate, please? Please note, my main argument is not to add the vendor, my main argument is to continue the historic notation (only because the historic tag notation includes the vendor it should be included here as well: office365 notation <> ms-office-2019, ms-office-2016, ...). For the windows tag this aspect is already fulfilled: Windows-10 notation = Windows-8, Windows-7 etc.)

Comment: I do get your point now. But there is also [office-2000], [office-2010-beta], [office-2013-preview], [office-for-mac], [office-communicator-2007]. I feel there is more harmonization to be done than just [office365].

Comment: @bers good point, thanks.